# sending a mail via php works but page times out

Tags: php, nginx, email, sendmail

I have a new server running ubuntu, nginx, php sendmail etc.

To test if sendmail is working I made a basic php file with the php mail function in it. When I execute the file my browser hangs until I get a 503 timeout but I still receive the test mail a few seconds later indicating sendmail is working.

Other pages on the server load just fine

The server does not have a domain name; I am just using its IP address for now.
There are no errors in the nginx error log but the mail log is showing errors like

```
sergeserver sm-msp-queue[13609]: unable to qualify my own domain name
```

Any ideas why and how to solve?

Here is the contents of `etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

# --- Gandi DHCP Script ---
95.142.166.209  sergeserver
# --- End ---

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Comment: What does the nginx error log say? [Check this](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#error_log) if you need help with error log configuration

Comment: This sounds more like an nginx configuration issue. You may want to check to logs at /var/log/nginx or the corresponding mail logs.

Comment: check the nginx error log - no errors reported. Other pages work fine and do not time out. There is `unable to qualify my own domain name` error in the mail log but I don't have a domain yet - just using the server IP

Comment: Please include the contents of /etc/hosts

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest hack to make this error message go is to try and add the following lines in your `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
Djsergeserver.example.net
```

**Do not use any random domain** as a FQDN. Use either a domain that you own, or example.net. After editing `sendmail.mc` make sure you generate `sendmail.cf` and restart sendmail. In Debian you do this with `sendmailconfig`. In CentOS you run `/etc/mail/make` followed by `service sendmail restart`.

Comment: OK, I shall try later when I get home. A few questions: why does it matter which domain I use? Can I use a domain I own but which is currently being used on another site? Will this cure the page timeouts?

Comment: It matters because $j holds the name by which your computer introduces itself to other computers during the SMTP dialog.

Comment: I added the line as you described and regenerated `sendmail.cf` but the issue persists

Comment: What does the `Dj` do before `sergeserver.example.net`?

Comment: It defines macro $j. Whatever the value for $j add it in your `/etc/hosts` files too.